# Cocoa @sum array operator too slow - alternatives?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sum, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I've got a text field value bound to a key path that uses @sum. When the array controller is filtered, the text field updates properly, but extremely slowly, lagging the UI or outright beachballing after every key press (less so as the number of items in arrangedObjects decreases). There is no lag if I don't use @sum; I've narrowed it down to this.

Is there a faster way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should have your answer:

http://cliffhacks.blogspot.com/2007/03/cocoa-bindings-sum-is-on-even-if-youre.html